# multiprocessing.Process hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Edited: Definitely this question needs more info...

My code launches several process like this one:

```
def my_process_executor(req, semaphore=None):
    try:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_stuff,args=(req,))
        p.daemon = False
        p.start()

        p.join(MAX_SECONDS_WAITING_FOR_PROCESS)

        if p.is_alive():
            # Too much time running, kill it!
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
    finally:
        if semaphore:
            semaphore.release()
```

When "semaphore" is None, everything works fine, even with a ton of concurrent processes.

But when "semaphore" has a value:

```
semaphore = threading.BoundedSemaphore(5)
```

Sometimes the subprocess never starts. Despite process.is_alive() returns true, do_stuff doesn't do anything.

Any idea? what's happening here?

Pay attention that do_stuff do not check the semaphore. So it doesn't hangs due to a "red light" on the semaphore.

Code is running on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and python 2.7

Comment: How many processes you have running simultaneously?

Comment: Last time it happened I was running just another 2 processes.